# How would I pause my background when my heroNode makes in contact with the enemyNode in Swift Spritekit?

Tags: swift, sknode

I'm trying to pause my background when my hero node makes contact with the enemy. When I use this code I posted below the speed of the background doesn't stop it keeps going its normal speed. I tried declaring the "city" globally only but I get an error saying `Attempted to add a SKNode which already has a parent`. What am I doing wrong?

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {    
    let city = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "skyline")
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    repeatCity()
}


func addCity() {
    let city = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "skyline")
    let moveToRight = SKAction.moveByX(-1000, y: 0, duration: 5.0)
    let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveToRight)



    city.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 0.7, self.size.height / 1.9)
    city.zPosition = 13
    city.setScale(0.9)
    city.runAction(repeatAction)
    addChild(city)


}

func repeatCity() {
    let generateBlocks = SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.runBlock(self.addCity),
        SKAction.waitForDuration(3.5)])
    let endlessAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(generateBlocks)
    runAction(endlessAction)

}
    func didBeginContact(contact:SKPhysicsContact){

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == HeroCategory && fourthBody.categoryBitMask == EnemyCategory {

        city.speed = 0
        theHero.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        println("contactwithEnemy!!!")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is, that you declare a class variable `city` but in your `add` method you use not the class variable but an own city-variable. So you should remove that class variable:

```
let city = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "skyline")
```

Now at the moment, the action which you repeat for ever on your `city` node keeps running. To stop that action you should remove all actions from the `city` node at contact:

```
self.removeAllActions()
```

Comment: Its still moving when I add it to the contact between the hero and enemy.

Comment: Does the if in the didBeginContact really happen?

Comment: Do you know if it could be anything else?

Comment: I've found the problem. You've declared city as a class variable but you don't use it in your addCity method. Remove the city-variable which you declare inside the addCity method and my code should work

Comment: the background is sill moving when I do this.

Comment: Try self.removeAllActions()

Comment: When I remove the city variable inside the addCity method I get an error saying "Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent". Also the self.removeAllActions() doesnt work either.

Comment: I think its the repeatCity() function thats not allowing me to pause the background.